# Can this "Bloody Fervor" effect be ended by a Calm Emotions spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, published-adventures, conditions, dnd-adventurers-league

In a recently published AL-Legal module contained within Pipyap's Guide to All the Nine Hells (available on the Dungeon Masters Guild), there is a "Bloody Fervor" effect (minor spoilers below):

> For every hour spent inside the Gorge, a creature must make a DC 25 Wisdom saving throw. If they fail, they must attack the nearest creature in the Gorge that succeeded on the saving throw. The effect only ends when the creature leaves the Gorge for more than one hour.

The *[calm emotions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/calm-emotions)* spell (PHB, p. 221) states:

> You attempt to suppress strong emotions in a group of people. Each humanoid in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on a point you choose within range must make a Charisma saving throw; a creature can choose to fail this saving throw if it wishes. If a creature fails its saving throw, choose one of the following two effects.
>   […]
>   Alternatively, you can make a target indifferent about creatures of your choice that it is hostile toward. This indifference ends if the target is attacked or harmed by a spell or if it witnesses any of its friends being harmed. When the spell ends, the creature becomes hostile again, unless the DM rules otherwise.

Let's say Fred the Fighter & Clarence the Cleric both spend an hour in the Gorge while staying close together. Fred then fails his Bloody Fervor saving throw, while Clarence succeeds it, thus making Fred compelled to attack Clarence. Assuming that leaving the Gorge is not an option, could Clarence cast Calm Emotions on Fred, choosing the second effect (quoted above) to prematurely end Fred's Bloody Fervor?

This is within the scope of Adventurers League play, where GMs must follow the rules more (and I'm asking as the GM).

Comment: Is that the entirety of the language regarding the module?

Comment: @NautArch For that specific effect, well, there’s a line stipulating that pit fiends & archdevils aren’t affected, but otherwise yea, I think that’s all there is to it.

Comment: I added a PHB page number and D&DBeyond link to the spell, but then realised that it says "DM" in my book. I'm guessing your quote said "GM" because it was from the SRD or something? I've changed it to "DM" to match the quote, but feel free to change it back to "GM" if you'd prefer (although I guess it would then be best to get rid of my PHB ref as well, since it then wouldn't be a direct quote anymore?)

Answer (score 4):

I would say no. The key part of the alternate use of calm emotions is that it makes the targets indifferent to creatures they are *hostile* towards. The bloody fervor effect doesn't make the creatures hostile towards each other, it just compels them to attack a target who passed their save. This is more akin to mind control like the [Dominate Monster](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dominate%20Monster) spell.

Answer (score 1):

## There is no language stating that the effect is due to emotion.

You assume that Fred will be enraged and feeling hatred towards Clarence. But this is never stated in the effect. It may well be that Fred's feelings towards Clarence doesn't change.

In your example Fred may be crying and repeatedly shouting "I'm sorry Clarence" as his is compelled to bash his friend's skull in. Even if you made Fred indifferent to Clarence, the beat down wouldn't end.